# Which value comes up first in df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my code and input:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'frame':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                    'label':['other','splenic','other','other','hepatic','other','other','other','hepatic','other','splenic','other']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'frame':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                    'label':['other','heaptic','other','other','splenic','other','other','other','splenic','other','hepatic','other']})
label = ['other','hepatic','splenic']
for i in range(0,len(label)):
    if label[i] not in 'other':
        start_frame = df1.loc[(df1['label']=='splenic'),'frame']
        end_frame = df1.loc[(df1['label']=='hepatic'),'frame']
    else: print('other')
```

Let's say I want mask start/end frame between two occur labels (`splenic` and `hepatic`) for further calculation. My problem is that in dataframes labels occur in a different order. For example in `df1`, `splenic` comes up first where `frame`=2  so it will be my `start_frame`. Next my `end_frame` is when I occur `hepatic` where `frame`=5. if we go further as next my `start_frame` will be `hepatic` where `frame`=9 and `end_frame` is `splenic` where `frame`=11. in df2 the order is reversed. There is no real pattern as to which comes up first.
So I can't say that is `splenic` will be my "start" and `hepatic` will be "end". It depends on which comes up first: `hepatic` or `splenic` so it will be "start", and second label will be "end" respectively.
What I expect for `df1`:

```
start_frame=[2,9]
end_frame=[5,11]
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected output? Because I am having difficulty understanding your explanation.

Comment: added what i expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to get every occurrence of one of your target labels:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'frame':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                    'label':['other','splenic','other','other','hepatic','other','other','other','hepatic','other','splenic','other']})

is_key = (df.label == "splenic") | (df.label == "hepatic")
```

Now we can extract the indices of the occurrences and set every (index of index in `id_key`) even to `start` and every odd to `end`:

```
id_key = np.where(is_key)[0]
start_frame_id, end_frame_id = id_key.reshape(-1, 2).T
```

The proper start and end frame are:

```
start_frame = df.loc[start_frame_id, "frame"]
end_frame = df.loc[end_frame_id, "frame"]
```

which results in:

```
>>> start_frame
1    2
8    9
Name: frame, dtype: int64

>>> end_frame
4      5
10    11
Name: frame, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'frame': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                    'label': ['other', 'splenic', 'other', 'other', 'hepatic', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'hepatic',
                              'other', 'splenic', 'other']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'frame': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                    'label': ['other', 'heaptic', 'other', 'other', 'splenic', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'splenic',
                              'other', 'hepatic', 'other']})


def get_label(dataframe):
    label = ['hepatic', 'splenic']
    start_val = end_val = ''

    for _, df in dataframe.iterrows():
        if df['label'] in label:
            start_val = df['label']
            end_val = label[label.index(start_val)-1]
            break

    start_frame = list(dataframe.loc[(dataframe['label'] == start_val), 'frame'].values)
    end_frame = list(dataframe.loc[(dataframe['label'] == end_val), 'frame'].values)
    
    return start_frame, end_frame


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start, end = get_label(df1)
    print(start, end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'frame':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                    'label':['other','splenic','other','other','hepatic','other','other','other','hepatic','other','splenic','other']})

# keep only rows with splenic or hepatic
df = df[(df.label == "splenic") | (df.label == "hepatic")]

# assign start/end, assumes there will be an even number of splenic/hepatic
df['tag'] = np.tile(['start','end' ], len(df)//2)

# from here you can extract the values you want
print(df)

# output

    frame    label    tag
1       2  splenic  start
4       5  hepatic    end
8       9  hepatic  start
10     11  splenic    end
```